# Tuning Op-Amp Integrator for Triangle Wave Generation

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, function-generator, square

I'm trying to simulate an op-amp integrator that can generate a triangle wave from a square wave. Unfortunately, my waveform is anything but triangular; if anything, it's another square wave with a longer transient than the input square wave.

[image: My current waveform output. The blue waveform is supposed to be triangular, but it's basically another square wave.]

It seemed to me that the transient was too fast, so I aimed to set my RC time constant such that the voltage across the capacitor would peak just as the square wave switched amplitude. Since my square wave runs at 200 kHz, I wanted five times the time constant to be equal to 2.5 microseconds.

$$5\tau = 5RC = 2.5\cdot10^{-6}$$
$$RC = 5 \cdot 10^{-7}$$

Unfortunately, as is visible from the waveform above, this didn't have any useful effects.

There are suggestions for resistor/capacitor values in other similar questions on this site, but the ones I found were specific to the application given in the question and did not provide a generalized method for finding optimal values for the auxiliary components.

**How should I solve for the correct values of my resistors and capacitor?**

(Note: In case it's useful, I chose a very large value for the feedback resistor R2 because it is my understanding that a larger feedback resistor allows for a higher frequency response in exchange for a larger DC bias error. Since the ultimate application for this triangle wave will be for current-mode control, I don't care much about bias, but want to maximize switching frequency. Of course, I'm not sure how to precisely quantify this tradeoff, so for all I know, this is overkill.)

Edit: OK, so in accordance with the advice of some friendly commenters, I increased the value of R1 to make sure that the current draw from the op-amp never exceeded its maximum of 15 mA. Once this value of R1 was chosen, I calculated the capacitance that would be necessary to have a 4V change across the capacitor in 2.5 microseconds. I'm super close to something triangular, but now I'm getting voltage spikes when the square wave switches polarity, presumably due to sudden changes in current draw. This makes the ramps discontinuous.

[image]

Comment: Have you really got a 0.5 ohm resistor on the input? What can the op-amp output current drive properly?

Comment: @Neil_UK meant 500m means 500 milli ohm, but not 500Meg ohm, though either of that is impractical.

Comment: @Neil_UK Not sure I follow. How would the resistor on the input limit the output current of the op amp?

Comment: @Neil_UK For what it's worth, though, I just went ahead and bumped R1 up to 47 ohms, then scale C1 down to 10 nanofarads. The waveform is MORE triangular-ish, but still not quite there. What's more, I truthfully don't understand why this made a difference, since I attempted to keep the RC constant roughly the same...

Comment: Fluffy, think about how much current is required to ramp up the voltage on the integrating capacitor. This current should certainly be *less than* the op amp's internal current limit...which you can find on its spec sheet.... \$ I=C{\Delta v \over \Delta t}\$

Comment: With typical setup, neglect R2 current and op amp bias current. Then current in R1 = current in C1. Thus V drop in R1 determines dV/dt in C1. Given a desired amplitude V and frequency, you can then calculate R1, C1 values.

Comment: @glen_geek Oh, interesting. I thought the current would be sourced by the square wave generator. But if I assume it's from the op amp, since the noninverting input is held at 2.5V and the square wave oscillates between 0V and 5V, then the current through the R2/C1 network must be capped at +/- (5V-2.5V)/0.5 = 5A. Assuming that the op amp is sourcing the current, this is indeed too high; The AD8551 datasheet says that the op amp puts out +/- 15 mA. So that would imply that I have to look at not only the RC value, but also set the value of R such that it's at least 2.5V/0.015A=166.67 Ohms.

Comment: OK, so glen_geeks' and Pete's suggestions have gotten me really close, but I'm not sure how to eliminate the voltage "jumps" that occur when the square wave switches polarity. (I edited the question to show what I mean.) My knee-jerk reaction to just add capacitors is probably misguided, since introducing capacitors to the input/output would mess with the generated waves, and introducing them to the intermediate stage would mess with the values that were just calculated. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your chosen op amp is not particularly speedy. It has gain-bandwidth-product of 1.5MHz. At first glance that may seem sufficient, considering your input frequency is 0.25MHz. But the peaks of your desired triangle wave require many harmonics to achieve their sharp slope transition, and your op amp must switch its current direction cleanly and quickly too. I'd suggest finding a faster opamp with high slew rate.